# HTML:Display paragraphs in a textbox

Tags: html

How to paste text in a textbox, text like

```
"abcdefghijklm...
      abcdefghijklm...".
```

When I do paste,only first line is displaying.Second line is skipped to display.

CSS:

```
 .Horse
{
    FONT-SIZE: 8px;    
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    COLOR: navy;
    FONT-FAMILY: TimesNewRoman;
}
```

Suggest some answers.

Comment: You should use textarea instead.

Comment: @yogi:No,I got to use textbox here.

Comment: that's not possible my frnd, textboxs are meant for single line inputs only. But whats the issue why can't you use `TeatArea` ?

Comment: @Yogi:Actually I prefer to enter single line text only,but in case if I need to copy paste text from other source in that case text will be skipped.

Comment: I don't understand your issue, look at this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U36Vq/4/) and if you copy and paste those paragraphs nothing is skipped. The input just strips out the new lines and you get 1 long string of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple lines in a text-type input (`<input type="text">`).

You'll have to use a `<textarea>`. That's all there is to it.

If you don't have access to the markup, but has access to JavaScript, you can dynamically replace it, though that's far less than ideal.

Answer (score -2):

You can set TextBox multiLine property  is true to make it become TextArea.

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide an example? According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) there is no 'multiLine' property for an input.

Comment: That means you are using HTML input. HTML has textarea input for u. I thought you are using .NET or other controls.